# Meteor: Check if the user is logged on startup

Tags: authentication, meteor

Whether the user is logged in or not, when I call `Meteor.user()` in `Meteor.startup()`, the user is always `undefined` (not logged).

I want to perform an action (redirect the user to an external url where the login must occur) if it is *not* logged in as soon as the page loads. The problem is that if he is logged in, the page will only know it at some point in time (in milliseconds, of course). I can trap the *eventual* logged in user with `Tracker.autorun`, but I want to perform an action **now** (when the user is always not logged in) and I know only **after** whether I need to perform it or not (maybe the user is already logged in).

How to do this in Meteor?

**EDIT**

I ended up with the following working:

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
    if (!Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn() && Accounts.loginServicesConfigured()) {
        Meteor.loginWithTwitter();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you try `Meteor.loggingIn()`, docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loggingin

Comment: you think my comment should post as answer, so we can close the question or you want to wait for a better answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Meteor.loggingIn()`

From the docs

`if a login method (such as Meteor.loginWithPassword, Meteor.loginWithFacebook, or Accounts.createUser) is currently in progress. A reactive data source.`

Answer (score 1):

One solution to the problem is to use [the `meteorhacks:fast-render` package](https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render). Its inclusion causes the initial set of data to be sent along with the application code, so the user information is available immediately in the `startup` method.

If you don't want to use that package, you can always restructure your app so that the "now" you speak of always happen after the initial data is loaded. For example, you can move this check to the `onBeforeAction` callback of your root controller. This will always run before any template is rendered, assuming you also subscribe to user data in the root controller.